# How to login from terminal using launchpad.net credentials?

Tags: login, launchpad, launchpadlib

I will share an example with you so that you can understand it better:

I am an authenticated user of launchpad.net. Now I want to login with my launchpad credentials to access this site's data.

I am able to do this as a public user and can login anonymously using

```
launchpad = Launchpad.login_anonymously('just testing', 'production', cachedir, version="devel")
people = launchpad.people
swati = people.getByEmail(email="xxx.yyy@zzz.com")
print swati.display_name
```

But I am not able to use the `login_with()` method of the API to login directly with my launchpad credentials and access its data.

Please share any commands you might have in mind for this.

Comment: What happens when you do use `login_with`?

Answer (score -1):

As explained [in the documentation](https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib#Authenticated_access), you can use the `login_with()` method to do so:

```
launchpad = Launchpad.login_with('id-of-your-program', 'production', credentials_file='./credentials', version='devel')
```

When you'll do something with the `launchpad` object that triggers a request to Launchpad, a Web browser page will pop up, asking you to log-in to Launchpad and/or to confirm you want to give access to your Launchpad account to this program.

The credentials will be stored in file `credentials`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `credentials_file` parameter is ignored since version 1.8.0 (2010-11-15).